# JQuery loop that pulls specific attribute of an element and adds it to the href

Tags: jquery, loops, jquery-selectors

So i've been working, searching, and smacking my head on the table all day over this.  I am vary VARY new to all of this so i'm sorry if my coding is incredibly junior.  What i'm trying to do is create a mechanism that remembers the anchor url of the current page but then when the user goes to change the nation alters the links in the nations page to bring the user back to exactly where they were but within the new nation directory.

Thus far i've gotten the selector pulling the info from the previous page and saving it as a cooky.  I even have it altering the urls just as i wanted.  The problem is that i gave each of the  tags a country code for the name.  When the code executes i can't get it to pull each name and apply it to the bespoke 's href as it moves through the page.  I've only been able to get the first one to select or the last one to witch it applies to all of them.  Any insight as to what i'm doing wrong would be awesome.

```
$('#setNation').click(function(event) {
   var fromPage = window.location.pathname
   $.cookie("pageFrom", fromPage);  
});

$('.nationSelect').each(function() {
   $('.nationSelect').attr("herf", "http://domain.com/"+$(this).attr("name")+$.cookie("pageFrom"));
});
```

And the HTMl Looks like this

```
<div id="nationList">
  <a name="de" class="nationSelect">
    <div id="nationListIcon">
      <div id="nationListImg" style="background-position: -229px -76px;"></div>
      <p lang="de" xml:lang="de">Deutschland</p>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a name="es" class="nationSelect">
    <div id="nationListIcon">
      <div id="nationListImg" style="background-position: -305px -76px;"></div>
      <p lang="es" xml:lang="es">España</p>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a name="fr" class="nationSelect">
    <div id="nationListIcon">
      <div id="nationListImg" style="background-position: -380px -76px;"></div>
      <p lang="fr" xml:lang="fr">France</p>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Thanks for all your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo. Its href, not herf. The herf sounds like something you pick up from a dirty girl.

```
//Your current code changes the href for all links of class nationSelect. This means whatever the last link changed is will be applied to all links on the page
$('.nationSelect').attr("herf", 

//What you want is for only the current one to get the new value. So use $(this)
$('.nationSelect').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('href', 'http://domain.com/' + $(this).attr('name') + '/morestuff');
});
```

Comment: I should mention that I have no clue what you are actually asking in your question, I am just assuming the typo is responsible. It would be helpful if you rephrased your question to be like. When I do X I want Y to  happen. This happens instead.

Comment: It's hard to explain. I want to add the "name" of the <a> to the url. When the page loads.  Each <a> has a different name.  So for instance the outcome of <a name="de"> should be href="domain.com/de/bla/bla/. Does that help at all?

Comment: Ah, I see what your problem is now. I updated my answer. When you set the `href` you need to use $(this) in the selector, not $('.nationSelect'). You are changing the href for every link on the page, not just the one you are interested in.